How to check the array indexof array of array
For example I have these array
total = [[0,1],[0,2]]

arr = [0,2]

apparently total includes the arr
However total.indexOf(arr) return -1
Is there any good way to solve this?

hint: [0,2] !== [0,2] - in fact [] !== []

try something like total.some(r => r.every((value, index) => value === arr[index])) it might work

Try JSON.stringify


const total = [[0,1],[0,2]]

const arr = [0,2]

const index = total.findIndex(item => JSON.stringify(item) === JSON.stringify(arr))

console.log(index)




Just keep in mind that this will work only if the internal arrays are sorted though!
